# Просмотр контейнера

Tags: c++, контейнеры

Создал класс для хранения пользовательского типа данных. Есть какая-то возможность теперь просмотреть этот контейнер?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Test {
private:
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    Test(string namee, int agee) {
        name = namee;
        age = agee;
    }
};

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    list <Test> q;
    list <Test> qq;
    srand(time(NULL));
        q.push_front(Test("Dima", 2));
        q.push_front(Test("Katya", 60));

}
```

Comment: `int main()`! Не `void`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
class Test {
private:
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    Test(string namee, int agee) {
        name = namee;
        age = agee;
    }
    string get_name() const { return name; }
    int    get_age()  const { return age;  }

};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    list <Test> q;
    list <Test> qq;
    srand(time(NULL));
    q.push_front(Test("Dima", 2));
    q.push_front(Test("Katya", 60));

    for(auto t: q)
    {
        cout << t.get_name() << " " << t.get_age() << endl;
    }

}
```